# Process.Start() and PATH environment variable

Tags: c#, path, process.start

I have the following trivial C# application that simply attempts to launch "jconsole.exe", which on my machine is located in C:\Programs\jdk16\bin.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace dnet {
  public class dnet {
    static void Main( string[] args ) {
      try {
        Process.Start("jconsole.exe");
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If my PATH environment variable is set to

```
c:\windows;c:\windows\sytem32;c:\programs\jdk16\bin
```

it works perfectly. However, if the PATH environment variable is set to

```
c:\windows;c:\windows\sytem32;c:\\programs\jdk16\bin
```

(note the two backslashes between "c:" and "programs"), it fails with a win32 exception.

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at dnet.dnet.Main(String[] args)
```

Interestingly, in the same command prompt where I run the .NET program and get the exception, I can simply type "jconsole.exe", and the program will start. Windows appears to have no trouble finding the executable with the double backslash in the PATH, but Process.Start() does.

Why is the extra backslash in the PATH causing problems, and how I can get around the problem? I don't know where the executable I want to call will be located at runtime, so I'd rather rely on the PATH variable.

Comment: There are two ways to start an EXE, you are testing both ways.  Your app uses ShellExecuteEx(), the command line interpreter uses CreateProcess().  You can play with ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute property.  There isn't much point in worrying about how they interpret the PATH environment variable differently, you know how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not quite sure why the problem occurs. Though, I can think of one solution that works on my machine:

```
var enviromentPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");

Console.WriteLine(enviromentPath);
var paths = enviromentPath.Split(';');
var exePath = paths.Select(x => Path.Combine(x, "mongo.exe"))
                   .Where(x => File.Exists(x))
                   .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(exePath);

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exePath) == false)
{
    Process.Start(exePath);
}
```

I did find one para which gave me the idea for this solution. From the [documentation for Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx)

> If you have a path variable declared in your system using quotes, you
>   must fully qualify that path when starting any process found in that
>   location. Otherwise, the system will not find the path. For example,
>   if c:\mypath is not in your path, and you add it using quotation
>   marks: path = %path%;"c:\mypath", you must fully qualify any process
>   in c:\mypath when starting it.

The way I read it, even though the `PATH` variable contained a valid path that Windows is able to use, `Process.Start` is unable to use it and needs the fully qualified path **.**

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the paragraph from the docs Amith.  I'd interpreted it as only affecting entries in the path with quotes, but I like your generalization that you can't trust Process.Start() to use the PATH environment variable properly.  As an interesting aside, I tried setting my PATH to `c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;"c:\programs\jdk16\bin"`, and Process.Start() was able to find jconsole.exe without any extra help.  This seems contrary to what the docs say, about Process.Start() using the PATH, so I really don't trust it now. :)

Comment: I recommend to use [System.IO.Path.PathSeparator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.pathseparator) to have multi platform support. On macos the path separator is ":".

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is incorrect.

cmd.exe will find applications with executable extensions first. 
So when you have the files `puma` and `puma.bat` in `C:\Ruby\bin\`, then `puma.bat` will take precedence over `puma`.

If you start `c:\ruby\bin\puma.bat` from `c:\redmine`, it will start puma with current working directory `c:\ruby\bin`, and your web application will work. 
However, if you start `c:\ruby\bin\puma` directly, it will start puma with the current working directory in `c:\redmine` and will subsequently fail.

So a corrected version looks more or less like this:

```
// FindAppInPathDirectories("ruby.exe");
public string FindAppInPathDirectories(string app)
{
    string enviromentPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
    string[] paths = enviromentPath.Split(';');

    foreach (string thisPath in paths)
    {
        string thisFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(thisPath, app);
        string[] executableExtensions = new string[] { ".exe", ".com", ".bat", ".sh", ".vbs", ".vbscript", ".vbe", ".js", ".rb", ".cmd", ".cpl", ".ws", ".wsf", ".msc", ".gadget" };

        foreach (string extension in executableExtensions)
        {
            string fullFile = thisFile + extension;

            try
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullFile))
                    return fullFile;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Log("{0}:\r\n{1}",
                     System.DateTime.Now.ToString(m_Configuration.DateTimeFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    , "Error trying to check existence of file \"" + fullFile + "\""
                );

                Log("Exception details:");
                Log(" - Exception type: {0}", ex.GetType().FullName);
                Log(" - Exception Message:");
                Log(ex.Message);
                Log(" - Exception Stacktrace:");
                Log(ex.StackTrace);
            } // End Catch

        } // Next extension

    } // Next thisPath


    foreach (string thisPath in paths)
    {
        string thisFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(thisPath, app);

        try
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(thisFile))
                return thisFile;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Log("{0}:\r\n{1}",
                 System.DateTime.Now.ToString(m_Configuration.DateTimeFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                , "Error trying to check existence of file \"" + thisFile + "\""
            );

            Log("Exception details:");
            Log(" - Exception type: {0}", ex.GetType().FullName);
            Log(" - Exception Message:");
            Log(ex.Message);
            Log(" - Exception Stacktrace:");
            Log(ex.StackTrace);
        } // End Catch

    } // Next thisPath

    return app;
} // End Function FindAppInPathDirectories
```

Answer (score 4):

You can solve it if you first create a `ProcessStartInfo`.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("jconsole.exe");
StringDictionary dictionary = psi.EnvironmentVariables;

// Manipulate dictionary...

psi.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] = dictionary.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
Process.Start(psi);
```

You'll have to find out yourself how to manipulate the PATH to let it work for you. But this should solve any issues you might have with your PATH variable.

Comment: After changing the [EnvironmentVariables property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables.aspx) , you have to have set the [UseShellExecute property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) to false.  However, if UseShellExecute is false, I must specify the fully qualified path for the [FileName property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename), which sort of defeats the purpose of changing the path.

Comment: Yet in the very example on the `UseShellExecute` page they do not give a fully qualified `FileName` and use `UseShellExecute = false;`. I've also tried setting it to false and just calling an exe that can only be found in my PATH and it just starts.

Comment: i would also recommand to set your `Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` with the environment path the your .exe should using

Comment: Note that `dictionary.Replace(@"\\", @"\")` will corrupt UNC-paths like `\\PCNAME\Public`, if someone uses them in `%PATH%`