# Win32 exception in C# application

Tags: c#

I am using the following code:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"java -jar path\Ontologizer.jar  -g   path\go.obo  -a   path\gene_association.fb  -m Benjamini-Hochberg -c Parent-Child-Intersection -p   path\back.txt  -s   path\genes.txt  -o path\outfull.txt");

process.StartInfo = info;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Dispose();
```

I get a Win32 exception:

> The system cannot find the file specified

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You probably have an error in your PATH environment variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392913/process-start-and-path-environment-variable

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, so it's clearly an issue with either the `path` or one of the filenames. We can't see your machine from where we are to figure out which one for you.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think I don't. When I copy and paste the processStartInfo to the command line everything works correctly. That's why I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: Do you need two backslashes to get this running ?

Comment: First argument for `ProcessStartInfo` constructor is a **file name**. And you file name is very weird.

Comment: @Marged i do not need it when I use 'at'

Comment: @PetSerAl When I leave only "java -jar  path\Ontologizer.jar" I get the same error

Comment: How about "java.exe"?

Comment: @PetSerAl Thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: @PetSerAl it looks like it'd be worth putting your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First argument of [`ProcessStartInfo` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b5zzxthe.aspx) should be file name only. All arguments to application should be putted into second argument of `ProcessStartInfo` constructor:

```
new ProcessStartInfo("java", @"-jar path\Ontologizer.jar  -g   path\go.obo  -a   path\gene_association.fb  -m Benjamini-Hochberg -c Parent-Child-Intersection -p   path\back.txt  -s   path\genes.txt  -o path\outfull.txt");
```