# The system cannot find the file specified in process.start

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me regarding this issue.

```
          string strEnvironmentalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
        startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@strEnvironmentalPath);           
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = "Knime.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = strParameters;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;           
        Process = Process.Start(@startInfo);          
        Process.CloseMainWindow();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.WaitForExit();
```

I get this error: **System cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: It seems that the file **Knime.exe** is not in your PATH. Please check this.

Comment: What is the use of creating a new `ProcessStartInfo` with the file name and then resetting the file name?

Comment: Obvious question really but ..... is Knime.exe in the current folder or in any of the folders listed in PATH.

Comment: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");`returns all the paths in the PATH variable...what's the point of passing that to the new ProcessStartInfo?

Comment: Try giving the absolute path for the  "Knime.exe" , only reason for this error might be its not able to find the "Knime.exe" in your "PATH"

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392913/process-start-and-path-environment-variable