# How to determine is app exists? (Process.Start can find them)

Tags: c#, winapi, registry

I use Process.Start for running apps. User can input path to app, e.g. "C:\SomePath\app.exe" and then Process.Start run this app. But I input e.g. "chrome.exe" Process.Start method run Chrome browser too! Where from Process.Start get full path for "chrome.exe"? How I can get this path too?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell, but your question looks like a duplicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12392913/21567). Hint: "PATH" environment variable.

Comment: PATH variable does not contain path to chrome.exe, but chrome.exe launching successfully whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a key in the registry where you can find chrome.exe path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe
```